# popover in angular ng-grid not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm using ng-grid to display data, I want to display line items in a popover when the mouse hover over this line, my probleme is that the popover does not overlay the ng-grid frame.

this is the  file :

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</body>
```

js file :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.toggle = false;
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        rowTemplate: '<div ng-mouseEnter="toggle = !toggle" ng-mouseLeave="toggle = !toggle" style="height: 100%;" ng-class=""><div ng-show="toggle" class="popover">Name : {{row.getProperty("name")}}<br>Age : {{row.getProperty("age")}}</div><div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}"><div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }">&nbsp;</div><div ng-cell></div></div></div>'
    };
});
```

CSS file :

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 200px;
    z-index:0;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
.popover {
    background:green;
    color: #fff;
    width:200px; 
    height:80px; 
    z-index:999999; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:10px; 
    left: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

you'll find here the source for my probleme http://plnkr.co/edit/t68djf?p=preview

thank you for help.

Comment: does anyone have an idea ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the definition of `.ngViewport` which is set to `overflow:auto` by default.

You can overwrite this with the following rule:

```
.ngViewport {
    overflow:visible;
}
```

But, as you will soon find out, this will lead to a lot of other display issues as soon as the gridheight changes or scrollbars come into play.

I haven't found a real solution for this but maybe this gives you an idea on how to proceed. Keep me informed when you found a way to do this.

Comment: hi mainguy, I tried that but it gives a problem of scrolling, thank you for the help